# Warning: DOMDocument::createTextNode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to append a node in the XML document. I have extracted the last itemid from my xml document and incremented it by 1 to add a unique id in the newly added xml node. But, when I do that, it throws error "Warning: DOMDocument::createTextNode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given". I even checked the type of variable using var_dump and it is string after I casted into string. But, I could not understand why such an error is coming up. Here, is the code.

```
    $xml =new SimpleXMLElement("goods.xml", null, true);

    // to get the last id
    $last = $xml->xpath("/items/item[last()]");

            // converted to integer
    $id = (int)($last[0]->itemid);

            // converted to string
    $itemid = strval($id+1);
    var_dump($itemid);

      $doc = new DomDocument( '1.0' );
      $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
      $doc->formatOutput = true;

    if( $xml = file_get_contents( 'goods.xml') ) {
        $doc->loadXML( $xml, LIBXML_NOBLANKS );

        // find the headercontent tag
        $items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('items')->item(0);

        $item = $doc->createElement('item');
        $item = $items->appendChild($item);

        $itemid = $doc->createElement('itemid'); 
        $itemid = $item->appendChild($itemid);   
        $value = $doc->createTextNode("".$itemid.""); // error occurs here
        $value = $itemid->appendChild($value);

        $itemname = $doc->createElement('itemname'); 
        $itemname = $item->appendChild($itemname);   
        $value = $doc->createTextNode($name);
        $value = $itemname->appendChild($value);

        $itemprice = $doc->createElement('itemprice'); 
        $itemprice = $item->appendChild($itemprice);   
        $value = $doc->createTextNode($price);
        $value = $itemprice->appendChild($value);

         $doc->save('goods.xml');
```

When in place of using $itemid, I simply use any text, this code works perfectly. I have just started learning XML, so please help if you know why this error is coming up when everything seems to be fine.

Thanks.

Comment: The code mismatches your error. Please do not copy over excerpts from your development code. Instead re-create an example from scratch that contains a minimum of code (and data) all in one chunk to reproduce the issue and showing the cause as concrete as possible. Here for example I doubt that many code is needed to show the issue and also the XML is missing.

Comment: Okay, I will take care of that. By the way, this issue was solved. I just added the $itemid without converting it into anything and it worked fine. I was assuming the conversion. Thanks for suggestion.